# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Workplace's [seventh moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/7) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: DarkCygnus]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/7), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4748460307775488/0).

Comment: congratulations to DarkCygnus

Comment: Congrats and good luck! I know you'll do great as a moderator.

Comment: Can't sure what's most appropriate between "congrats" and "my condolences" ;) welcome to the (quite big) team of SE mods.

Comment: Fantastic, great to see!

Comment: Congrats and good luck!

Comment: Congratulations, DarkCygnus. Let us know how we can help.

Comment: Thank you to all the candidates who ran. A terrific field this go-round!

Comment: Congratulations DarkCygnus, and thank you to everyone who participated. We had an excellent field of candidates once again.

Comment: Congrats @DarkCygnus :)

Comment: Thanks to everybody for your kind messages :)

Comment: Great, maybe you can do something about the psycho troll.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations. Make sure nobody poops in your office and/or slits your seats while you are not on duty :P

Comment: Congrats! @DarkCygnus :)

Comment: Well done, it was a strong field.